# Explain the code to create a textfield using java

Tags: java, swing, layout, jframe, jtextfield

Can anyone help me understand the below code that creates a textfield ? A summary about the following code would be very useful.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class CreateNewJTextField extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public CreateNewJTextField() {
        // set flow layout for the frame
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        JTextField field3 = new JTextField(10);

        add(field3);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new CreateNewJTextField();
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        createAndShowGUI();
    }

}
```

Comment: -1 Please add some description of your problem.

Comment: -1 for the format and no question mark

Answer (score 3):

In CreateNewJTextField:

```
this.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
```

This create a Pane and sets a default layout. Pane is like a piece of paper on which you draw.

```
JTextField field3 = new JTextField(10);
add(field3);
```

This creates a text field and adds it to that pane.

In createAndShowGUI, you are adding this pane to a JFrame(the frame with minimize, close buttons), which is like a drawing board.

```
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

Then you set the visibility of the frame, define what should happen on clicking close button.

Comment: It creates an instance of the class CreateNewJTextField. Read the basics of Java!